# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str' Simpleton

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is so simple that none of the messages that I have found so far deal with my low level problem but here is my code.

```
name=input("What is your name?")
weight=input("How much do you weigh?")
target=input("What would you like to weigh?")
loss=weight-target
print("So...",name,'You need to lose',loss,"pounds!")
print("\n\nPress enter key to scram!")
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/davebrown/Desktop/Pract.py", line 7, in <module>
    loss=weight-target
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

I don't understand why is it unsupported?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot substract `str` object. ([`input`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) in Python 3.x returns `str` object unlike [`input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) in Python 2.x)

```
>>> '2' - '1'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Convert them into [`int`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) or [`float`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) first.

```
>>> int('2') - int('1')
1
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the strings to integers first which can be done using the built-in [`int()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) or [`float()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#float) functions

So Try this instead:

```
weight= int(input("How much do you weigh?"))
target= int(input("What would you like to weigh?"))
```

## Note:

*In python, You cannot perform mathematical functions such as division or subtraction  on a string without converting it to a integer first However string addition and multiplication can be performed*, **However for your case neither string addition or multiplication will work**

Example:

```
>>> 'Hi' + ' Bye!'
'Hi Bye!'
>>> 'Hi' * 5
'HiHiHiHiHi'
```

Comment: So i guess `'foo' + 'bar'` and `'bar' * 5` are both incorrect?

Comment: @kroolik sorry I fixed it.

Comment: I've downvoted it for the time it had that incorrect statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are apparently using python 3. The result of `input` is always a string, so you must convert them to integers before you can do arithmetic. (In python 2, `input` will interpret what you type in as python code, so your code would have worked as intended).

```
weight=int(input("How much do you weigh? "))
```

etc.

You can "add" strings together with `+`, but there's no corresponding subtraction operation. And if there was, given the way string "addition" works, subtracting `"25" - "5"` would have given you `"2"`! So you you must convert to integers to get the intended result (a corresponding program about *gaining* weight would not have triggered a python error, but would have given very worrisome results).